# Can I use jQuery to change a CSS property for a CSS class, not a matched element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use jQuery to set the `margin-left` property for a CSS class.

```
$('.first_note').css('margin-left',50);
```

Only one element on my page will ever have the class `first_note`.

I need to remove the `first_note` class from the element, and apply it to another element. The problem is when I do, the previous first_note still has the `margin-left` value of 50, and the new one doesn't.

It's because in that jQuery code I'm applying the css property to the element. What I actually need to do is change the property for the class itself. Is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

@Ben, I think in this case I'd do it this way;

1. Create a class called say Margin50.
2. I'd then set the classes in jQuery
   accordingly.

So if you have your two elements, the first one uses removeClass for first_note and also the Margin50 and then apply first_note and Margin50 to the next element.